# How do I secure a API without requiring sign-in

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core

I'm just starting to research client certificates. I have a web API built with .NET Core on Azure App Service. Is it possible to secure the API so that only my angular application can access it? Perhaps with client certificates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure API Management and require subscription key for any of the API consuming applications to send them in HTTP Headers.

Comment: Also, can use Managed identity to be assigned to your angular App Service, and grant only to that in your web API.